# Что означает !r в python

Tags: python

Я первый раз такое вижу, что означает `!r`?

```
logging.info(f'Request: {request.json!r}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просто подсказка питону, что Вы хотите вызвать метод repr для перевода в строковое отображение. Детали https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#s-r-and-a-are-redundant

Answer (score 2):

Использование для `f-строки` данной записи не является необходимым, оставлено для обратной совместимости. Изначально это использовалось в  `str.format()` согласно [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) это флаги конверсии для преобразования значения. Поле преобразования вызывает приведение типа перед форматированием.

В настоящее время поддерживаются три флага преобразования:

- `!s`, который вызывает str() для значения,
- `!r`, который вызывает repr(),
- `!a`, который вызывает ascii().